# Is it ok to call tkinter root.after from a thread other than the one running root.mainloop()?

Tags: multithreading, tkinter

A regular GUI. As a result of certain user actions a CPU-bound computation taking several seconds must be run. In order to keep the GUI responsive the computation is run in a separate thread. Now, while the computation is running, the user may change some parameter that affects its result; should that happen, a flag will be raised.

After the computation ends, *still in the thread's target,* the flag is checked. If set, we know the computation result is inconsistent with the current state and we must rerun the computation.
I'd like to do that by calling `root.after(..., rerun)` *from the thread*. Is that OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer to your question is yes as long as your other thread is aware of the root object you can do this. Your root object would have to be in the global space and not its own thread though. You would have to declare your root object as a global variable in your other thread `global root` In my experience, I have found that multithreading does not play well with tkinter and even though your window will technically be responsive it can get laggy(to the point that it is no longer responsive). I would suggest using subprocess to run your computations which may require you to put that code in its own script, but it would achieve your program requirement of having a responsive GUI. https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Comment: But using subprocesses would require to pipe the arguments to the computation and pipe the results back. Each can be several megabytes.

Comment: It is up to you how you do it. I can tell very little about your program requirements from your question. Ultimately it is for you to decide how to do it. I'm just trying to save you some time as I've tried to use tkinter with multithread and had to redo a lot of code to get something that left me with a responsive GUI. Try these resources. http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-your-gui-app-freezes.html http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580754-long-processing-computation-in-tkinter-or-long-run/

Comment: ShayneLoyd, you were right about multithreading and tkinter. The computation starves the event loop and the GUI becomes unresponsive. I switched to multiprocessing and the problem was solved. Computations take a bit longer because of the piping of arguments and results but not much more. Even better, I don't have to wait for the completion of a computation that I know to be useless, I can kill the process. Thanks.